# Loading shared libs using Android.mk

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

How can I specify shared libraries to load in the Android.mk when compiling with ndk-build ?

**Edit:** This is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := lib-crypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libcrypto.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := tema1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tema1.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := lib-crypto
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /home/aleksei/openSSL0.9.8/include
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

libcrypto.so is the library that I have built for android. I want to make a program using it. Now it gives me this error:

```
Install        : libcrypto.so => libs/armeabi/libcrypto.so
Executable     : tema1
./obj/local/armeabi/libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `dladdr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/tema1] Error 1
```

Comment: @Mr.32 I have to mention that the libcrypto. so has already been built using ndk-build for android. And that the include path points to the headers of the openSSL I have installed for ubuntu, but it should be the same thing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. To fix it, I did the following:

1. In the same directory as your Android.mk file, create a file named Application.mk
2. Add the following line of code into Application.mk:
   `"APP_PLATFORM := android-8"`

If you already have an Application.mk file, just add the code in step 2 to the existing file. Now call ndk-build and see if it links. ndk-build may be compiling with an old version of libdl which does not have dladdr(). The code in step 2 will cause ndk-build to use an updated libdl which has dladdr().

Answer (score 1):

```
PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY
    Points to a build script used to specify a prebuilt shared library.
    Unlike BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY and BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY, the value
    of LOCAL_SRC_FILES must be a single path to a prebuilt shared
    library (e.g. foo/libfoo.so), instead of a source file.

    You can reference the prebuilt library in another module using
    the LOCAL_PREBUILTS variable (see docs/PREBUILTS.html for more
    information).
```

read more from http://source-android.frandroid.com/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html

Show me what you have done till yet and where you facing problem.?